# Error when accessig the API Requests:- Could not retrieve Global Service Principal ID Error: Error: {}

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

I am trying to approve some API Requests >> but i will get this error "Could not retrieve Global Service Principal ID Error: Error: {}", any advice?

[image]

any advice please?

Thanks